# Creating a Java object through Ajax

Tags: java, ajax, json, spring

I'm new to ajax and JSON (and programming in general), but what I'm trying to do is use ajax to convert my JSON object into a Java object but I keep getting "Required LocationsList parameter 'myJSONObject' is not present". Am I expecting too much of ajax here? I was told the fields in my LocationsList would be filled in automatically.

Ajax stuff:

```
function getAffectedFlowsForLocation(myJSONObject) {
//JSON.stringify(myJSONObject) looks like {"stations":["111", "222"],"stationGroups":["333"],"others":[]}

    $.ajax({
    url : baseUrl + "/locations/getFlowsAffectedByDelete",
    type : "GET",
    data : "{'myJSONObject':'" + JSON.stringify(myJSONObject)+ "'}",
    dataType : "json",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    async : false,
    success:function(data){
        displayAffectedFlows(data);
    },
    error : function(){
        // error is handled by global ajaxError()
        success = false;
    }
});
```

}

In the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getFlowsAffectedByDelete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<Map<String, String>> getFlowsAffectedByDelete(@RequestParam(value = "myJSONObject") final LocationsList locations) {
    //returns a List<Map<String, String>>
}
```

My LocationsList:

```
public class LocationsList {

private List<Integer> stations;

private List<Integer> stationGroups;

private List<Integer> others;

//Getters and setters
}
```

Let me know if anything needs clarification.

Thanks

Comment: You're using Spring, right?

Comment: AJAX cannot create Java objects, you are mixing up the concepts. How does you GET request look like?

Comment: Yep I am, though my spring knowledge isn't huge. I'm just following previous examples others have done to make my own implementations work.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
   @RequestBody LocationsList locations
```

instead of

```
   @RequestParam
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the way you are using the `data` attribute. From the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests.

So, it should be an object:

```
data : { myJSONObject : JSON.stringify(myJSONObject) },
```

or a string:

```
data : "myJSONObject=" + JSON.stringify(myJSONObject),
```